# Unable to create bdist_egg in pycharm - error: package directory 'venv\Lib\site-packages\pip-10\0\1-py3\6\egg\pip' does not exist

Tags: python-3.x, package, pycharm, setup.py

Running the `bdist_egg` through PyCharm fails with the error -

> error: package directory
>   'venv\Lib\site-packages\pip-10\0\1-py3\6\egg\pip' does not exist

I noticed that the `setup.py` contains `venv.Lib.site-packages.pip-10.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip`

However, I find the following package available in path `venv/Lib/site-packages/pip-10.0.1-py3.egg/pip`.

Comment: Don't add venv dir to project's source roots, this breaks pycharm project. Instead, select `venv/bin/python` as project interpreter.

Comment: You'll also need to remove and recreate the existing `setup.py` script after adjusting the settings mentioned in above comment.

Comment: The project's source does not include venv folders(Excluded in the Project structure). Also the Project interpreter is already \venv\Scripts\python.

Comment: Then remove `setup.py` script (or move it to backup) and generate it again. If this doesn't help, add the screenshot of the project structure from settings and the project tree view to the question.

Comment: Fixed the problem, found this after searching - https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3678. However, it is mentioned that the dots in the package names should be converted to hyphens as part of the canonical naming convention. I was hoping PyCharm would take care of it. I renamed the folder in lib replacing dots with hyphens and i was able to proceed. Thanks @hoefling for your help.