# error: package directory 'venv\Lib\site-packages\pip-10\0\1-py3\6\egg\pip' when attempting to package Python project

Tags: python

As the title says, I am attempting to package up my project, using the command `py setup.py sdist`.

However, when I run the command I get the following error: `error: package directory 'venv\Lib\site-packages\pip-10\0\1-py3\6\egg\pip'`even though the directory does exist. I have had a look at the question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50996346/unable-to-create-bdist-egg-in-pycharm-error-package-directory-venv-lib-site) but that hasn't helped with the issue unfortunately.

My question is how can I fix this, considering the directory *does* exist.

-Thanks